# discord.py the massban command doesn't work?

Tags: python, discord.py

so I've made this simple script to test it on a test server, the code gives no errors / logs yet it doesn't function, bans no one to be exact. Any ideas? (Only for testing and educational purposes only.)

````
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import colorama
from discord import Permissions
from colorama import Fore, Style
import asyncio

token = "token"


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="y!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('''
  
  READY
  ''')
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="test"))


@client.command()
async def bonk(ctx):
  for user in ctx.guild.members:
    try:
      await user.ban()
    except:
        pass

client.run(token, bot=True)```
````

Comment: it gives no errors because you suppress errors with your `try/except` block

Comment: so is there a way to fix that and make it work..?

Comment: Have you imported Intents?

Comment: nope, haven't imported Intents

Comment: You can check for exceptions by replacing the `except` with `except Exception as e:` and printing `str(e)`, which will provide the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Intents are missing as you stated that you did not import them. Without Intents you can't catch all the members in a guild.

Make sure to turn on all the necessary ones in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) for your application.

**To implement them to your code you can use the following:**

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all() # Imports all the Intents
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="YourPrefix", intents=intents)
```

*You can also read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html) for more information.*

**Your full code would be:**

```py
Imports shortened

token = "token"

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="y!", intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('''READY''')
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="test"))


@client.command()
async def bonk(ctx):
  for user in ctx.guild.members:
    try:
      await user.ban()
    except:
        pass

client.run(token, bot=True)
```